# Redirecting to backend via htaccess Yii2

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, yii2

I am trying to redirect my url to the admin ( backend ) part on `domain/admin` via htaccess. Still not very familiar with `.htaccess` and what I did so far is
Main `.htaccess` in the root directory:

```
#adding the charset
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

#hide the structure
Options -Indexes
#if dir is symbol, follow it
Options FollowSymlinks

#engine on
RewriteEngine 

#if there is admin word in the URI go on the next rule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin$ 
#load the backend index file, append the group to the url (QSA) and stop rewriting (L)
RewriteRule ^admin(/.+)$ /backend/web/$1 [QSA,L]

#everything different from admin ( because of the previous rule ) go on the next rule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
#load the frontend index file append the group to the url (QSA) and stop rewriting (L)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /frontend/web/$1 [QSA,L]
```

And this is my backend/frontend `.htaccess` ( they are same ):

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

The frontend is ok e.g `domain/site/about` lets say but the backend `domain\admin` gives `404 not found`. Did I understand what i wrote right ? Where is my mistake? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression matches **only exactly** the characters */admin*.

Your regex matches:

1. the start of the string with `^`
2. exactly the characters `/admin`
3. the end of the string with `$`

If some characters are found after `n` then it does't match and it won't apply the rule.

If you want to match any request that **starts** with *admin* then try:

```
#if there is admin word in the URI go on the next rule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^admin(.*)$ 
#load the backend index file, append the group to the url (QSA) and stop rewriting (L)
RewriteRule ^admin(/.+)$ /backend/web/$1 [QSA,L]
```

That would match urls in your domain that start with *admin* but followed by any characters.

If you wanted to match any urls that **contain** the word *admin* then you need to write:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)admin(.*)$
```